# How to make autosuggest suggestions overflow the dialog container?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, autosuggest

How to make autosuggest suggestions be position above the dialog and not in the dialog? To avoid dialog content scrolling

Sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/embed/adoring-bogdan-pkou8[image]

Comment: Why not just make the dialog bigger in height?

Comment: In my case I want to make container suggestions to position above the dialog. To make the dialog height bigger isn't a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the libraries that you are using, but the outer dialog div element with class name `MuiPaper-root MuiPaper-elevation24 MuiDialog-paper MuiDialog-paperScrollPaper MuiDialog-paperWidthSm MuiPaper-rounded` needs an `overflow: visible` style. 
And the `MuiDialogContent-root` div element needs `overflow-y: unset`.
For me this does the trick in the code sandbox.

To explain this behaviour: the dialog crops of everything that vertically overflows his boundaries and creates a scrollbar for that. Because the autosuggest component is DOM-wise inside the dialog component and positioned `absolute` it is cut off when getting bigger than the dialog. Telling the dialog to not crop it's content and not hide overflowing content by scrolling, lets the autosuggest component overflow correctly. But it also means you can't scroll inside the dialog anymore.

You should let the autosuggest component let its root element append to the body and position itself with the input field as pivot point. That way you don't have to manipulate the overflows, because the autosuggest is DOM-wise "above" the dialog component.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add max-height to the Paper component that renders the suggestions.

```
renderSuggestionsContainer={options => (
    <Paper  style={{'maxHeight':100, overflow:'auto'}} {...options.containerProps} square>
         {options.children}
    </Paper>
)}
```

Comment: It isn't that I'm searching for. max-height - doesn't position suggestion container above the dialog

Comment: If you add this max-height to the suggestions list, it will have a separate scrollbar. So your problem of scrolling the modal content will get solved. What do you mean by position above the dialog? Try it - https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-visvesvaraya-l0ewj?fontsize=14